# How to cache rules fetched by vmalert?

Tags: victoriametrics

My system’s architecture works such that a vmalert instance is fetching its alerting rules from an external api.
However, I’ve noticed that if the api is down, vmalert crashes with it. Is there a cache mechanism I can activate via an environment variable such that if it fails to fetch rules it will use the previously fetched ones?

If not, what is suggested to do such that vmalert will not crash on rule fetching?

Comment: Would you mind [to create an issue](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/new/choose) and add more information like vmalert version with environment scheme?

Comment: > However, I’ve noticed that if the api is down, vmalert crashes with it

What way of fetching the config for alerting rules do you use? What does the crash message say?

In general, vmalert will fail to start if it can't read the configuration (from file, web URL or object storage). It is done on purpose, so if there is a mistake in config (wrong path or URL) - user could spot it instantly. If config gets reloaded  in runtime and there is error - vmalert will continue working with previous version of config and will emit metrics and logs notifying about unsuccessful config reload.